# What files should I import, so I can make Bootstrap custom range thumbs work?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's custom form range, though its thumb is not working, even if I import `scss/_bootstrap.scss` manifest file. It works only when `dist/bootstrap.css` is imported or I'm using the CDN.

That's my manifest file for importing Bootstrap files:

```
// Required abstracts
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

/*----------------------------- OPTIONAL -----------------------------*/

// abstract
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/display";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/flex";

// base
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";

// layout
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";

//components
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
```

And that's my HTML code:

```
<input id='quantity' 
       class='custom-range' 
       type='range' 
       min='12' 
       max='18' 
       step='2'
       value='12'>
```

After importing these files, the range thumb won't style as expected (it keeps browsers default style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [WebCompiler extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) for Visual Studio and is compiling the Bootstrap Sass file, you need to add support for [Autoprefixer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/build-tools/#autoprefixer) in the compilerconfig.json:

```
{
  "outputFile": "wwwroot/css/site.css",
  "inputFile": "wwwroot/css/site.scss",
  "options": {
    "autoPrefix": "last 2 versions"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've opened an issue and this dude says it is a node-sass problem, as it is working perfectly with dart-sass, tho I haven't had the time to test it. Have you tried it? Issue link: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28145

Comment: @JoãoLucas Indeed, Autoprefixer was the problem!